# Spacetime transformation in field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, coordinate-systems, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I'm trying to understand Noether's theorem in QFT.
I stumbled across one small doubt,
Please explain why is there a negative sign instead of plus sign in the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mike stone's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/725179/289541) can be explained in a more detailed way. The transformation acts on the coordinates, not the field. So the field at a point in the spacetime remains the same after the transformation.

For any transformation $x\to Tx$,
the field after the transformation is marked as $\phi'(x)$, and before
transformation it is $\phi(T^{-1}x)$, where $T^{-1}$ is the inverse of the transformation.

In OP's case, $Tx=x+a$ and $T^{-1}x=x-a$. Thus
$$
\phi(x)\to\phi'(x)=\phi(x-a)=\phi(x)-\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_\nu}a_\nu.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation solves my query.

Answer (score 5):

If $f(x)$ has its maximum at $x=0$, then $f(x-a)$ has its maximum at $x=a$, so displacing a function through a   displacement   $\delta x=a$ requires
$$
f(x)\mapsto (T_af)(x)= f(x-a)\approx f(x)- a \partial_x f.
$$